# creating a vector of objects

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have just coded while on the train this, that creates a vector of objects. 
I would appreciate if someone has a suggestion to make it more elegant or effective?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

typedef struct{
    short xpos,ypos;
    short width, height;
    short area;
}LABELPROP;

int get_property(int n,LABELPROP *pP)
{
    if(n%2)
    {
        pP->xpos=n*2;
        pP->ypos=n*3;
        return 1;
    }
    else return 0;
}

int main()
{
  vector<LABELPROP> myvector;
  cout<<"Initial Number :"<<myvector.size()<<endl;
  LABELPROP temporal;
//  LABELPROP *pT=&temporal;

  for(int n=1;n<=10;n++)  //10 objects
  {
    //if(get_property(n,pT))
    if(get_property(n,&temporal))
        myvector.push_back(temporal);
  }

  for(int i=0;i<myvector.size();i++)
      cout<<"("<<myvector[i].xpos<<","<<myvector[i].ypos<<")"<<endl;

   return 0;
}
```

As you can see I eliminated an unnecessary pointer that I originally put.

the temporal struct gets its values from the get_property function so that is why I put that as a pointer

Thanks in advance

Comment: Off topic: The typedef gag is not needed in C++.

Comment: If your program works as intended and you are looking for suggestions on improving it, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a better site. Make sure to read up on [their guidelines for posting](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) before posting there.

Comment: Use a reference rather than a pointer here: `int get_property(int n,LABELPROP *pP)`. the compiler may have additional avenues for optimizing a reference over a pointer and it also eliminates the possibility that a null pointer is passed in.

Answer (score 2):

You are writing C++ in a C style.  You don't need to typedef your struct, just use:

```
struct LabelProp
{
    LabelProp(short xpos, short ypos) : xpos(xpos), ypos(ypos) {}
    short xpos,ypos;
    short width, height;
    short area;
};
```

I also changed the naming, because most conventions use all uppercase names as constants or macros.  I also added a constructor to be used.

You have `get_property` returning an `int`, but since this is c++, return a `bool`.

Probably an even better idea would be replace `get_property` with `addIfOdd` and have it look something like:

```
void addIfOdd(int n, std::vector<LabelProp>& results)
{
    if(n%2)
    {
        results.emplace_back(n * 2, n * 3);
    }
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<LabelProp> myvector;

  for(int n=1;n<=10;n++)  //10 objects
  {
       addIfOdd(n, myvector);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! it is a rather very elegant solution. Unfortunately I just found the compiler I am working with does not implement "emplace_back"

Comment: so I used push_back with a temporal struct

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are unnecessarily iterating over a full range of integers when it is in fact the odd numbers that you're after. Why not limit the range to odd numbers? (only half as many iterations), *e.g.*:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 10; i += 2) { /* 1, 3, ..., 9 */ }
```

---

Using modern C++ you could add a constructor to your class:

```
explicit label_prop(int n)
    : xpos{static_cast<short>(n * 2)}, ypos{static_cast<short>(n * 3)} {}
```

and replace all your code with a `std::generate_n`, *e.g.*:

```
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(myvector), 5, [n = 1] () mutable {
    return label_prop{std::exchange(n, n + 2)};
});
```

Here, you're specifying that you want 5 consecutive odd numbers, starting at 1.

Answer (score 1):

If your compiler is modern enough and supports C++11 features, you could use the new range-based for loop, like this:

```
for(auto& x : myvector)
    cout<<"("<<x.xpos<<","<<x.ypos<<")"<<endl;
```

Also, in order to improve the eficiency you can use the [reserve](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) method if you know in advance the size of the vector, so that you can avoid unnecessary object reallocations and memory allocations/deallocations, which can be expensive.